# Javascript unexpected token ILLEGAL in line-break

Tags: php, javascript, line-breaks

I render some data with `Twig` and do somethink like this:

```
var products = {
    {% for item in items %}
    {{ item.id }} : {
        'title': '{{ item.title }}',
        'info': '{{ item.info }}',
    }
}
```

There is an error, caused by line breaks in `item.info` variable.

I tried some tricks: replace `\n\r` to `<br />` etc.

What should I do?

**UPD #1**

Error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

**UPD #2**

The replacement of `\n` and `\r` does without problems. The problem is that I need variable to be **with line-breaks**, not in one line.

Comment: Did you check that that replacement actually worked? The Windows line break sequence is \r\n, not \n\r. To catch any sequence of \r and \n, you can use a regex to match '[\r\n]+'. Also, please post the actual error you're getting, or if it's simply not giving the expected behavior, explain in more detail.

Comment: Adding the error message would probably be helpful

Comment: I think you can use the ["json_encode()"](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) filter to handle this case, or else the ["escape()"](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html) filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try end each line with a backslash i.e \
For example

```
console.log("Line\
New")
```